# serialize values of aggregate results from sqlalchemy using marshmallow

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am performing a `count()` and `group_by()` operation on a table as follows:

```
db.session.query(func.count(Tag.name), Tag.name).group_by(Tag.name).limit(limit)
```

and serialize it using marshmallow:

```
class TagSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
    name = fields.String(validate=validate.Length(min=1))
```

which gives me result as :

```
[{"name" : "asdf"},{"name":"qwer"}]
```

but I don't see the count value, how should I update the schema to get count value in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first label the count field as :

```
db.session.query(func.count(Tag.name).label('count'), Tag.name).group_by(Tag.name).limit(limit)
```

and then add a new shema as:

```
class TagCountSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    name = fields.String()
    count = fields.Int(dump_only=True)
```